# Is glDrawElements synchronized on back buffer?

Tags: opengl

If I call `glDrawElements` with the draw target being the back buffer, and then I call `glReadPixels`, is it guaranteed that I will read what was drew?

In other word, is `glDrawElements` a blocking call?

Note: I am observing an weird issue here that may be caused by `glDrawElements` not being blocking...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In other word, is glDrawElements a blocking call?

That's not how OpenGL works.

The [OpenGL memory model](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model) is built on the "as if" rule. Certain exceptions aside, [everything in OpenGL will function ***as if*** all of the commands you issued have already completed](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Synchronization). In effect, everything will work as if every command blocked until it completed.

However, this does not mean that the OpenGL implementation actually works this way. It just has to do everything to make it *appear* to work that way.

Therefore, `glDrawElements` is generally not a blocking call; however, `glReadPixels` (when reading to client memory) *is* a blocking call. Because the results of a pixel transfer directly to client memory must be available when `glReadPixels` has returned, the implementation must check to see if there are any outstanding rendering commands going to the framebuffer being read from. If there are, then it must block until those rendering commands have completed. Then it can execute the read and store the data in your client memory.

If you were [reading to a buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object), there would be no need for `glReadPixels` to block. No memory accessible to the client will be modified by the function, since you're reading into a buffer object. So the driver can issue the readback asynchronously. However, if you issue some command that depends on the contents of this buffer (like mapping it for reading or using `glGetBufferSubData`), then the OpenGL implementation must stall until the reading operation is done.

In short, OpenGL tries to delay blocking for as long as possible. Your job, to ensure performance, is to *help* OpenGL to do so by not [forcing an implicit synchronization](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Synchronization#Implicit_synchronization) unless absolutely necessary. [Sync objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sync_Object) can help with this.